# How to turn a dict value that's a list into a tuple to then invert the dict

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, tuples

My assignment requires to create a dictionary with a list of values for each key. Then, it provides an invert function and asks to modify the function so that every item in the list is a new key. My understanding is this.
a={'a':['2','3','4'], 'b':['1','5','6']}
b={'2':'a', '3':'a','4':'a','1':'b','5':'b','6':'b'}

I created a test dictionary with tuples instead of lists and I was able to invert them but I don't know how to turn the lists in the dictionary into tuples and then into individual items that would correspond to the same value.
I watched youtube tutorials and tried googling it (including stack overflow) but cannot get how to complete it.
At this point, I don't even know anything - I would definitely appreciate any explanation as I feel completely confused.

````
def invert_dict(d):
     inverse = dict()
     for key in d:
          val = d[key]
          if val not in inverse:
               inverse[val] = [key]
          else:
               inverse[val].append(key)
     return inverse

#my initial dictionary
work_contacts={'Lauren' : '617-111-2222', 'Sana' : '781-234-1212', 'Kelly': '845-234-1515', 'Jose' : '946-999-3210', 'Sabrina' : '617-222-5656', 'Shirika' : '410-231-9090', 'Rachel': '823-432-2121'}

c=invert_dict(work_contacts)
c
{'617-111-2222': ['Lauren'], '781-234-1212': ['Sana'], '845-234-1515': ['Kelly'], '946-999-3210': ['Jose'], '617-222-5656': ['Sabrina'], '410-231-9090': ['Shirika'], '823-432-2121': ['Rachel']}
c['617-111-2222'] #calling the first key
['Lauren']

#the dictionary for the assignment
work_contacts={'Lauren' : ['617-111-2222', 'lauren@company.org'], 'Sana' : ['781-234-1212', 'sana@company.org'], 'Kelly': ['845-234-1515', 'kelly@company.org'], 'Jose' : ['946-999-3210', 'jose@company.org'], 'Sabrina' : ['617-222-5656', 'sabrina@company.org'], 'Shirika' : ['410-231-9090', 'shirika@comoany.org'], 'Rachel': ['823-432-2121', 'rachel@company.org']}

#the error comes back like this
invert_dict(work_contacts)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#10>", line 1, in <module>
    invert_dict(work_contacts)
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 5, in invert_dict
    if val not in inverse:
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

#I tried to turn the lists into tuples
def l_t(s):
    final = []
    for k, v in test.items():
        if v in final:
            final.append(k)
        final = tuple(final)
    return s

l_t(work_contacts)
{'Lauren': ['617-111-2222', 'lauren@company.org'], 'Sana': ['781-234-1212', 'sana@company.org'], 'Kelly': ['845-234-1515', 'kelly@company.org'], 'Jose': ['946-999-3210', 'jose@company.org'], 'Sabrina': ['617-222-5656', 'sabrina@company.org'], 'Shirika': ['410-231-9090', 'shirika@comoany.org'], 'Rachel': ['823-432-2121', 'rachel@company.org']}

def l_t(s):
    p=s
    final = []
    for k, v in test.items():
        if v in final:
            final.append(k)
        final = tuple(final)
    return p

l_t(work_contacts)
{'Lauren': ['617-111-2222', 'lauren@company.org'], 'Sana': ['781-234-1212', 'sana@company.org'], 'Kelly': ['845-234-1515', 'kelly@company.org'], 'Jose': ['946-999-3210', 'jose@company.org'], 'Sabrina': ['617-222-5656', 'sabrina@company.org'], 'Shirika': ['410-231-9090', 'shirika@comoany.org'], 'Rachel': ['823-432-2121', 'rachel@company.org']}

`def l_t(s):
    p=s
    final = []
    for k, v in p.items():
        if v in final:
            final.append(k)
        final = tuple(final)
    return p

l_t(work_contacts)
{'Lauren': ['617-111-2222', 'lauren@company.org'], 'Sana': ['781-234-1212', 'sana@company.org'], 'Kelly': ['845-234-1515', 'kelly@company.org'], 'Jose': ['946-999-3210', 'jose@company.org'], 'Sabrina': ['617-222-5656', 'sabrina@company.org'], 'Shirika': ['410-231-9090', 'shirika@comoany.org'], 'Rachel': ['823-432-2121', 'rachel@company.org']}

#I then tried to tuple the values 
tuple(work_contacts.values())
(['617-111-2222', 'lauren@company.org'], ['781-234-1212', 'sana@company.org'], ['845-234-1515', 'kelly@company.org'], ['946-999-3210', 'jose@company.org'], ['617-222-5656', 'sabrina@company.org'], ['410-231-9090', 'shirika@comoany.org'], ['823-432-2121', 'rachel@company.org'])

#I have generated much more code with error messages, as below
b=invert_dict(test)
b
{(2, 'al', 3): ['a'], ('we', 'as', 4): ['blue']}

b[2]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#145>", line 1, in <module>
    b[2]
KeyError: 2
b(2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#146>", line 1, in <module>
    b(2)
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
b(2, 'al', 3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#147>", line 1, in <module>
    b(2, 'al', 3)
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
b[1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#148>", line 1, in <module>
    b[1]
KeyError: 1```
````

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear to me what you want to solve.

However if you are trying to convert the following

```
{'a': [2, 3, 5], 'b': [7,11]} => {2: ['a'], 3: ['a'], 5: ['a'], 7: ['b'], 11: ['b']}
```

Then you could use the following

```
{v1: [k] for k, v in original_dict.items() for v1 in v}
```

*some extra words*
to invert the dictionary I iterate through the original dictionary as per the

```
for k, v in original_dict.items() => ('a', [2, 3, 5]), ('b', [7,11])
```

the second step is to iterate through the values, `v`

```
[m for k in [[1,2], [3,4]] for m in k] => [1,2,3,4]
```

This step also shows how list comprehension works - where we can iterate through nested lists.

you have all the tools now to see how you can use the same logic for creating the dictionary.

Comment: Thank you!
Would you be able to walk me through `{v1: [k] for k, v in original_dict.items() for v1 in v}` in words so I can understand what I'm doing?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're asking how to modify `invert_dict` into a function that will work on your second `work_contacts` dictionary, the one with lists as its values. If not, ignore this answer!

Let's look at the function:

```
def invert_dict(d):
     inverse = dict()
     for key in d:
          val = d[key]
          if val not in inverse:
               inverse[val] = [key]
          else:
               inverse[val].append(key)
     return inverse
```

If `d` has lists as its values, then `val` will be a list. This line:

```
if val not in inverse:
```

is where your function is throwing an error. Lists can't be used as keys in dictionaries; in the jargon of Python, `list` is an unhashable type. That's what the error is complaining about.

If you want the keys in the inverted dictionary to be the elements of the list, not the list itself, you just have to loop over the list and do the same thing with its elements that you were doing with the original `val`. Try something involving:

```
val_list = d[key]
for val_element in val_list:
     if val_element not in inverse:
          # you do the rest!
```